Is there a way to check whether current editor group is the first editor group in VSCode?
VSCode provide a command: workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup to focus buffer of first editor group.
But what I need is:
After I press `<option+l>`
if current group is the first one
    focus Explorer
else
    move to previes editor group

So I need to check whether current group is the first group.
Is there a way to make it? Thanks!

You can cycle between the VSCode panes using workbench.action.navigateRight or workbench.action.navigateLeft
[
    {
        "key": "alt+l",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateRight"
    },
    {
        "key": "alt+h",
        "command": "workbench.action.navigateLeft"
    },
]


There is a context key you can use: activeEditorGroupIndex.
If the active editor is in the first group then activeEditorGroupIndex will = 1, and so on.
So try these keybindings:
{
  "key": "alt+l",         // whatever you want, just make it the same as below
  "command": "workbench.files.action.focusFilesExplorer",
  "when": "activeEditorGroupIndex === 1"
},
{
  "key": "alt+l",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusPreviousGroup",
  "when": "activeEditorGroupIndex !== 1"
}

