VSCode: Context key to detect left/right split pane?
I'm working with Visual Studio Code and trying to create a custom keybinding that behaves differently depending on whether the cursor is in the left or right pane of a split editor.
My question is:
Are there any context keys in VSCode that can detect whether the active editor is in the left or right pane of a split view?
If not, is there an alternative way to achieve this distinction in keybindings or settings?
I've searched the VSCode documentation and experimented with various context keys, but so far haven't found a solution. Any insights or workarounds would be greatly appreciated.
Environment:
Visual Studio Code Version: Version: 1.89.1 (User setup)
OS: Windows_NT x64
I've enabled Developer Mode and used the "Developer: Inspect Context Keys" command to search for relevant context keys, but haven't found anything that distinguishes between left and right split panes.

What exactly would you like to do invoke in either pane? What should it do?

I'm trying to set up a seamless navigation system in VS Code using keyboard shortcuts. Currently, I use Ctrl+Shift+H to focus the sidebar when it's visible and the previous editor group when it's not. I use Ctrl+Shift+L to focus the next editor group when the sidebar is not in focus and the previous editor group when it is.
What I'd like to achieve is a continuous navigation loop: I want to move from the sidebar to the first split, then to the second split, and back to the sidebar again using Ctrl+Shift+L. Similarly, I want to move in the reverse direction using Ctrl+Shift+H.

Hm, it makes sense and sounds doable, but conditionals will be a challenge. // OT: My setup is ctrl+pg for tab switching, ctrl+shift+pg for moving tab in group, ctrl+alt+pg for switching between groups and ctrl+shift+alt+pg for moving tabs across groups. For jumping to and from sidebar I've slightly amended default Ctrl+0 to get it two-ways ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/49668291/540955 ). And yes, for me the (lack of) default focus movement bindings in VSC are quite a conundrum.

similar question to https://stackoverflow.com/q/78265420/11107541

Try the following keybindings:
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusFirstEditorGroup",
  "when": "sideBarFocus"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusNextGroup",
  "when": "!activeEditorGroupLast && !sideBarFocus"
},

{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+l",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusSideBar",
  "when": "activeEditorGroupLast && !sideBarFocus"
},

{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+h",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusLastEditorGroup",
  "when": "sideBarFocus"
},
{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+h",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusPreviousGroup",
  "when": "activeEditorGroupIndex !== 1 && !sideBarFocus"
},

{
  "key": "ctrl+shift+h",
  "command": "workbench.action.focusSideBar",
  "when": "activeEditorGroupIndex === 1  && !sideBarFocus"
}

The above will open the SideBar if it is closed.  It isn't clear to me if that is your desired behaviour or if you want to ignore the SideBar if it isn't open.  Let me know and I can change the above.

Thanks for the response; something similar to this worked perfectly for me.

Most probably you can get pretty far using groupEditorsCount and activeEditorGroupIndex:


Thanks for the response; this helped me figure it out.
